# How can I animate several widgets at the same time?

Tags: flutter

Flutter.   There are two screens. On the first screen, there is one widget in the center (a container with text). On the second screen (ListView), the same (container with text), but shifted to the side, and another one is added(TextField). How do I animate the transition between these screens? Move the first widget (container) I know how. But how do I add a TextField at the same time ? ......as an option, I thought to apply the opacity of the TextField , but this place on the first screen is already occupied. Probably a complete replacement of the screens is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example of quick animation. This code should be in `onpressed`

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
      transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secAnimation,
          Widget child) {
        animation = CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);

        return ScaleTransition(
          scale: animation,
          child: child,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        );
      },
      transitionDuration:
          const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secAnimation) {
        return **urpage**();
      }));
```